# Deployed my Next.JS app too firebase hosting but I do not see any functions in the firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js, firebase-hosting

I followed this tutorial to deploy my Next.JS app to firebase:
https://itnext.io/deploying-next-js-app-to-firebase-functions-eb473791d79e

The output of my deploy script results in this:

```
i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing . directory for uploading...
i  hosting[hacks-life]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[hacks-life]: found 5 files in public
✔  hosting[hacks-life]: file upload complete
i  hosting[hacks-life]: finalizing version...
✔  hosting[hacks-life]: version finalized
i  hosting[hacks-life]: releasing new version...
✔  hosting[hacks-life]: release complete

✔  Deploy complete!
```

So when i go to the hosting url i get this:

> Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL
> /nextjs-server/ from this server.

So i was thinking maybe there is an issue with my function not being deployed even though it seems to have been from the script output.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead?  We can't see what you're trying to deploy, so we can't explain what happened here.  Please edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: @strangeQuirks did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Somehow yes, but cant remember exactly, think it was the firebase authentication